# Questions on the XML editor in Eclipse

Tags: xml, editor

I am using Eclipse (for RCP) to create a XML file, I notice that there are Design and Source tab for the xml file, please see the photo below for more detail:
http://img6.ph.126.net/_XEDpd6P2MvYWt4mkYH7rg==/2686115702767268286.jpg

I have two questions:
1. How can I view the source code of the UI for Design tab? (Which jar does it belong?)
2. How does the Design tab tie to the Source tab? How can they synchronize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). Unfortunately a lot of the documentation on the link below is out of date, and I'm not sure if they have migrated their source from CVS to Git (the Eclipse platform has moved over to Git). I would post this question in the WTP forum if you can't figure out how to get to the XML editor source from the link below.

Comment: Clone the repository shown at http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/ .  The org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui plug-in project has the source code.